# But when I run this program I get an error like this:"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test1.txt'"

Tags: python

```
import os, sys, stat

file1=open("test1.txt","w") 
status=os.stat("test1.txt")

file1.write("Hello World")

os.chmod("test1.txt",stat.S_IRUSR)

print(file1.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

To the `os.chmod` before you are opening the file. You are opening the file without executable permissions in unix system. So you are getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the file, you should close it and re-open in 'read' mode:

```py
import os, sys, stat

file1=open("test1.txt", "w")
status=os.stat("test1.txt")
file1.write("Hello World")
os.chmod("test1.txt",stat.S_IRUSR)
file1.close()

file1=open("test1.txt", "r")
print(file1.read())
file1.close()
```

Or, even better:

```py
import os, sys, stat

with open("test1.txt", "w") as file:
    status=os.stat("test1.txt")
    file.write("Hello World")
    os.chmod("test1.txt",stat.S_IRUSR)

with open("test1.txt", "r") as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Comment: Why not simply open the file for read and write? `w+` for truncate the file first and then read or write; or `r+` for read and write without truncating

Comment: I think you are right, and `w+` mode would work. But `r+` mode would only work if the file exists already.